# Convert simple array into array of objects and add new property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array

```
const databaseName = ['Oracle','Mysql','MongoDb'];
```

the expected output is

```
const database = [
{
  name:'Oracle',
  isAvailable:true
},
{
  name:'Mysql',
  isAvailable:true
},
{
  name:'MongoDb',
  isAvailable:true
}
]
```

This has to be done using Javascript and es6.

i have tried using

```
const database = {...databaseName ,isAvailable:true}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from doing it?

Comment: Hint: You want to use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Your snippet attempts to create a single object, while the question indicates you want to end up with an array. Seems like you’d want to start by figuring out how to turn one array into another; there are multiple approaches you could take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const databaseName = ['Oracle','Mysql','MongoDb'];

console.log(
  databaseName.map(name => {
    return {
      name,
      isAvailable:true
    }
  })
)
```